# Does Magento 1.9.0.1 need php-redis extension for using Redis Cache?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Does Magento 1.9.0.1 need php-redis extension for using Redis Cache?
I can't seem to be able to find the answer through google.

Edited: it looks like there is an option whether to use phpredis or standalone PHP

```
<force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
```

Comment: if you use force_standalone as 1, then you need to make your php code redis compatible, which can happen only if you use or create your own library for redis otherwise it would be as good as not using redis.

Comment: ah i see. so it's safer if i leave it to 0. thanks

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee

    In addition, you can optionally use the Redis extension for PHP  version 2.2.3 or later if you're using Redis for back end caching; however, Magento works without this extension

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.0.1 comes along with Cm_RedisSession the way it is for magento 1.8. You need to have redis installed on your server, you need to have a PHP extension for interfacing with Redis. The details can be found at http://pecl.php.net/package/redis.

And you can refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee#config-mage for configuring redis.